# How to find database connection info from Windows 7/MS Access

Tags: oracle, connection, odbc, ms-access-2007

I've been asking MS Access query questions, but I have determined that I need to get to my library's Oracle RDBMSserver directly. I installed SQL Developer, which I used a lot in my programmer job before my current position.  Apparently MS Access 2007 cannot handle subuqeries as fields. My issue right now is how to find the connection info to the database server. This info has to be stored somewhere in order for MS Access to use an ODBC driver to get data, but after looking around the Windows 7 control panel-administrative tools-ODBC tabs, and reading several Google results, I'm not finding what I need. These values have to be stored someplace. How can I find them please?  Thanks.

Ken

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure of what you are asking. Win7 uses the registry to hold ODBC connection information. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/110507